# What are the possible ways for JSON data processing using SQL, elastic search or preprocessing using python

Tags: python, sql, elasticsearch

I have a case study where i need to take data from a REST API do some analysis on the data using aggregate function,joins etc and use the response data in JSON format to plot some retail grahs.

Approaches being followed till now:

1. Read the data from JSON store these in python variable and use insert to hit the SQL query. Obviously it is a costly operation because for every JSON line read it is inserting into database.For 33k rows it is taking more than 20 mins which is inefficient.
2. This can be handled in elastic search for faster processing but complex operation like joins are not present in elastic search.

If anybody can suggest what would be the best approach (like preprocessing or post processing in python) to follow for handling such scenerios it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

**Sql Sript**

```
def store_data(AccountNo)

        db=MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        insert_query = "INSERT INTO cstore (AccountNo) VALUES (%s)"
        cursor.execute(insert_query, (AccountNo))
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return

def on_data(file_path):
        #This is the meat of the script...it connects to your mongoDB and stores the tweet
        try:
           # Decode the JSON from Twitter
            testFile = open(file_path)

            datajson = json.load(testFile)
            #print (len(datajson))

            #grab the wanted data from the Tweet
            for i in range(len(datajson)):
                for cosponsor in datajson[i]:
                    AccountNo=cosponsor['AccountNo']
                    store_data( AccountNo)
```

Edit1: Json Added

```
{
    "StartDate": "1/1/18",
    "EndDate": "3/30/18",
    "Transactions": [
        {
            "CSPAccountNo": "41469300",
            "ZIP": "60098",
            "ReportDate": "2018-03-08T00:00:00",
            "POSCode": "00980030003",
            "POSCodeModifier": "0",
            "Description": "TIC TAC GUM WATERMEL",
            "ActualSalesPrice": 1.59,
            "TotalCount": 1,
            "Totalsales": 1.59,
            "DiscountAmount": 0,
            "DiscountCount": 0,
            "PromotionAmount": 0,
            "PromotionCount": 0,
            "RefundAmount": 0,
            "RefundCount": 0
        },
        {
            "CSPAccountNo": "41469378",
            "ZIP": "60098",
            "ReportDate": "2018-03-08T00:00:00",
            "POSCode": "01070080727",
            "POSCodeModifier": "0",
            "Description": "PAYDAY KS",
            "ActualSalesPrice": 2.09,
            "TotalCount": 1,
            "Totalsales": 2.09,
            "DiscountAmount": 0,
            "DiscountCount": 0,
            "PromotionAmount": 0,
            "PromotionCount": 0,
            "RefundAmount": 0,
            "RefundCount": 0

}
]
}
```

Comment: 33k rows might just fit in memory, can you use `pandas`?

Comment: No it's not just 33k rows. I have data for too many years. So  think doing it in memory would not be a good way

Comment: You cannot know,  until you try it if your hardware can master that amount of data or not. May be it can even handle 1M rows of that file structure! Apart from that I  would use `executemany` instead of `execute`: What was the reason why you are trying to read again row by row an write into the db  row by row? Because it will bring some extra cost to you.

Comment: It's an array like JSON structure i'm reading from the file storing all the fields in separate python variable so that i can pass them as columns to store data function

Comment: @Emre i have added my json structure as well

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your json file so not know if it is runnable, but I would have tried something like below: I read just your account infos to a list and than try to write to the db at once with `executemany` I expect it to have a better(less) execution time than 20 mins.

```
def store_data(AccountNo):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=HOST, user=USER, passwd=PASSWD, db=DATABASE, charset="utf8")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO cstore (AccountNo,ZIP,ReportDate) VALUES (:AccountNo,:ZIP,:ReportDate)"
    cursor.executemany(insert_query, AccountNo)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    return

def on_data(file_path):
    # This is the meat of the script...it connects to your mongoDB and stores the tweet
    try:
        #declare an empty list for the all accountno's
        accountno_list = list()

        # Decode the JSON from Twitter
        testFile = open(file_path)

        datajson = json.load(testFile)
        # print (len(datajson))

        # grab the wanted data from the Tweet
        for row in datajson[0]['Transactions']:
            values = dict()
            values['AccountNo'] = row['CSPAccountNo']
            values['ZIP'] = row['ZIP']
            values['ReportDate'] = row['ReportDate']
           #from here on you can populate the attributes you need in a similar way..
        accountno_list.append(values)
    except:
        pass                    
    store_data(accountno_list)
```

Comment: It's not just a single column that is being calculated i.e accountno. There are other columns as well around 100+ so appending it to a list doesn't sounds like a great idea

Comment: i have added my json structure as well

Comment: I have just improved the code and populated by two other attributes as **ZIP** and **Reportdate**. You can populate for other wanted attributes by yourself as in a similar way.  It might be runnable now, if you adjust the `store_data` method before. Give it a try, I expect much better execution times. 33k rows should not be a issue for a standard computer. For every row defining a dictionary and appending it to a list generates the data format what the **bulk insert** we are doing looking for.

Comment: it will anyways come in the form of a dictionary like below          :                                          [{'ReportDate': u'2018-03-30T00:00:00', 'ActualSalesPrice': 2.49, 'CSPAccountNo': u'414693', 'DiscountCount': 0, 'Description': u'NEURO WHT RASPBE', 'ZIP': u'60098', 'PromotionAmount': 0.0, 'POSCode': u'89940700401', 'RefundAmount': 0.0, 'Totalsales': 2.49, 'TotalCount': 1, 'RefundCounts': 0, 'DiscountAmount': 0.0, 'PromotionCount': 0, 'POSCodeModifier': u'0'}]